# Update of multi-object state and input values on toggle not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components namely, 'SectionFruits' & 'ToggleFruit' and a state called 'selectedFruits' which is an array of objects like so:

```
useState([
  {
    name: 'Apple',
    price: '',
    quantity: '',
  },
  {
    name: 'Mango',
    price: '',
    quantity: '',
  },
])
```

'ToggleFruit' is a component which has the logic of add/remove fruit's properties (name, price, quantity) like so:

```
import React, { useState, createRef } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledToggleFruit = styled.div`
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  & > div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    input[type="checkbox"] {
      margin: 0;
    }
    h6 {
      margin: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      color: coral;
    }
  }
  aside {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 2px;
    input {
      margin-right: 8px;
    }
  }
`;

const ToggleFruit = ({
  Id,
  state,
  setState,
  ischecked,
  label,
  price,
  quantity
}) => {
  const toggleRef = createRef();
  const [priceValue, setPriceValue] = useState(price);
  const [quantityValue, setQuantityValue] = useState(quantity);
  const [checkedState, setCheckedState] = useState(
    ischecked ? ischecked : false
  );

  const handleToggle = (e) => {
    setCheckedState(!checkedState);

    if (state.some((object) => object.name.includes(label))) {
      const removeFruitArr = state.filter((item) => item["name"] !== label);
      setState(removeFruitArr);
    } else {
      setState((prevState) => [
        ...prevState,
        {
          name: label,
          price: priceValue,
          quantity: quantityValue
        }
      ]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <StyledToggleFruit>
      <div onClick={handleToggle}>
        <div>
          <input
            ref={toggleRef}
            onChange={handleToggle}
            ischecked={ischecked && ischecked.toString()}
            checked={checkedState}
            type="checkbox"
          />
        </div>
        <h6>{label}</h6>
      </div>
      {checkedState && (
        <aside>
          <input
            required
            onChange={(e) => setPriceValue(e.target.value)}
            value={priceValue}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Price"
          />
          <input
            required
            onChange={(e) => setQuantityValue(e.target.value)}
            value={quantityValue}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Quantity"
          />
        </aside>
      )}
    </StyledToggleFruit>
  );
};

export default ToggleFruit;
```

And 'SectionFruits' simply runs a map over FRUITS and renders them in the DOM. There are two issues I'm facing:

1. The toggle(add/remove) of fruits in the state is behaving weirdly
2. Price & Quantity are not being added to the state

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-haze-5ono9

Comment: Also, how do I add required validation for the price & quantity fields, assuming the 'Log Fruits' button is 'Save'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited a bit your code on `codesandbox`, please check it out:
https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-estrela-5yqbs?file=/src/components/ToggleFruit.js:660-676